# Can atomic instructions straddle cache lines?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, cpu-architecture

Can x86 instructions like `LOCK DEC` straddle multiple cache lines, or will they seg-fault?

Not asking if they *should*, just whether its allowed.

(I know certain SSE instructions must be aligned on cache boundaries)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's allowed. You could have also just tried it. Or read the instruction set reference:

> The integrity of the LOCK prefix is not affected by the alignment of
>   the memory field. Memory locking is observed for arbitrarily
>   misaligned fields.

But see also:

> Exceptions
>
> #AC(0) If alignment checking is enabled and an unaligned memory reference is made while the current privilege level is 3.

Note that alignment checking is not usually enabled.

Answer (score 4):

It's allowed, but you might get a huge performance degradation as the lock may not be possible to maintain inside the cache, and may downgrade into a full bus-lock (a full system stall, effectively).

See for e.g. - https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/implementing-scalable-atomic-locks-for-multi-core-intel-em64t-and-ia32-architectures :

> In the days of Intel 486 processors, the lock prefix used to assert a
>   lock on the bus along with a large hit in performance. Starting with
>   the Intel Pentium Pro architecture, the bus lock is transformed into a
>   cache lock. A lock will still be asserted on the bus in the most
>   modern architectures if the lock resides in uncacheable memory or if
>   the lock extends beyond a cache line boundary splitting cache lines.
>   Both of these scenarios are unlikely, so most lock prefixes will be
>   transformed into a cache lock which is much less expensive.

It may vary according to the processor spec, but note that one other consideration is that crossing line boundary may also mean crossing a page boundary, which is even harder to maintain (and thus even more likely to downgrade).